# How to declare array of zeros in python (or an array of a certain size)

Tags: python

I am trying to build a histogram of counts... so I create buckets.
I know I could just go through and append a bunch of zeros i.e something along these lines:

```
buckets = []
for i in xrange(0,100):
    buckets.append(0)
```

Is there a  more elegant way to do it? I feel like there should be a way to just declare an array of a certain size.

I know numpy has `numpy.zeros` but I want the more general solution

Comment: Python's lists are lists, not arrays. And in Python you don't declare stuff like you do in C: you define functions and classes (via def and class statements), and assign to variables which, if they don't exist already, are created magically on first assignment. Also, variables (and lists) are not memory regions that contain, but names refering to, objects. One object can be contained in only one memory region but can be referenced by several names.

Comment: Python doesn't have "declarations", especially of containers with a size but unspecified contents. You want something, you write an expression.

Comment: ...and the semicolons are completely unnecessary

Comment: **Not a duplicate**. The perceived need for an air-quotes empty list starts a different conversation about list allocation and assignment. Also there should be two landing pages for the different search terms, which the stats indicate are common.

Answer (score 522, accepted):

```
buckets = [0] * 100
```

Careful - [this technique doesn't generalize to multidimensional arrays or lists of lists](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list). Which leads to the [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly) problem

Answer (score 151):

Just for completeness: To declare a multidimensional list of zeros in python you have to use a list comprehension like this:

```
buckets = [[0 for col in range(5)] for row in range(10)]
```

to avoid reference sharing between the rows.

This looks more clumsy than chester1000's code, but is essential if the values are supposed to be changed later. See the [Python FAQ](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) for more details.

Comment: Yup, you're right, unless for some strange reason you want to operate on n copies of the same array :)

Answer (score 29):

You can multiply a `list` by an integer `n` to repeat the `list` `n` times:

```
buckets = [0] * 100
```

Answer (score 24):

Use this:

```
bucket = [None] * 100
for i in range(100):
    bucket[i] = [None] * 100
```

OR

```
w, h = 100, 100
bucket = [[None] * w for i in range(h)]
```

Both of them will output proper empty multidimensional bucket list 100x100

Comment: What about `bucket = [[0] * w] * h`?

Comment: @RobinHood by using your idea bucked[0][x] would be **always** the same as e.g. bucket[1][x]. Even after changing bucket[0][x].

Answer (score 20):

use numpy

```
import numpy
zarray = numpy.zeros(100)
```

And then use the [Histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) library function

Comment: Sorry, but numpy.zeros was explicitly excluded.

Answer (score 7):

The question says "**How to declare array of zeros ...**" but then the sample code references the Python list:

```
buckets = []   # this is a list
```

However, if someone is actually wanting to initialize an array, I suggest:

```
from array import array

my_arr = array('I', [0] * count)
```

The Python purist might claim this is not *pythonic* and suggest:

```
my_arr = array('I', (0 for i in range(count)))
```

The *pythonic* version is very slow and when you have a few hundred arrays to be initialized with thousands of values, the difference is quite noticeable.

Comment: Hi, and why isn't the `array('I', [0] * count)` slow? I'd assume it will first create a full list and based on that full list then create the array, which sounds... terrible. I would guess that laziness would actually be quite beneficial in your last code snippet and make it run faster?

Comment: I can't attest to the *why* ... I can modify my code based on performance results. I didn't include results already confirmed by consensus.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be

```
"\x00" * size # for a buffer of binary zeros
[0] * size # for a list of integer zeros
```

In general you should use more pythonic code like list comprehension (in your example: `[0 for unused in xrange(100)]`) or using `string.join` for buffers.

Comment: I agree that the list comprehension looks more Pythonic. However, I timed it, and found that it's about 10x slower than the multiplication syntax. I know, something something preoptimization evil.

Comment: I am creating an `array('I')` and was using `(0 for i in range(count))` to fill ... and it is very slow: 28000 items in the array. The multiplication syntax is much faster. If 'pythonic' equates to slow, then its out with the 'pythonic' and in with *fast*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're actually going to do with the data after it's collected, collections.defaultdict(int) might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Well I would like to help you by posting a sample program and its output

Program :-

```
t=input("")

x=[None]*t

y=[[None]*t]*t

for i in range(1,t+1):

      x[i-1]=i;
      for j in range(1,t+1):
            y[i-1][j-1]=j;

print x

print y
```

Output :-

```
2

[1, 2]

[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

I hope this clears some very basic concept of yours regarding their declaration. To initialize them with some other specific values,like initializing them with 0..you can declare them as :

x=[0]*10

Hope it helps..!! ;)

Answer (score -4):

If you need more columns:

```
buckets = [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.] for x in range(0)]
```