# Initialising an array of fixed size in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I would like to know how i can initialize an array(or list), yet to be populated with values, to have a defined size.

For example in C:

```c
int x[5]; /* declared without adding elements*/
```

How do I do that in Python?

Comment: All of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+array+of+fixed+size.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, forcing a list to a fixed size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944708/python-forcing-a-list-to-a-fixed-size)  Or maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056768/how-to-declare-array-of-zeros-in-python-or-an-array-of-a-certain-size

Comment: The more interesting question is *why* you want to do this. Most of the situations where I've seen this needed are because of bad decisions.

Comment: You almost never need this. In 99% of the cases you can generate the values in one swoop, e.g. using a list comprehension, or you simply start with `[]` and `.append()` or `.expand()` in a `while` loop or something like that (lists are over-allocating so resizing is amortized O(1)).

Comment: You should explain your motivation for needing this. Performance? Security? Interfacing with C/C++/NumPy/...?

Comment: `x = [0]*5` will provide the equal opposite of `int x[5]`

Comment: A C array *has* its elements as soon as it’s created, even if you can’t use them yet because their values are indeterminate.

Comment: Also you can `[None for i in range(26)]`

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed, the question linked and used to close this specified a list. A better answer to declare an integer array of size 'length' is:
import array
my_array = array.array( 'h', [ 0 ] * length )

Comment: Initializing an array in advance of filling it can be useful for dynamic programming algorithms, where the order in which the array is filled is not straightforward. For example, I can't imagine an easy way to fill a 2D array diagonally using list comprehensions

Answer (score 426, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> lst = [None] * 5
>>> lst
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: The question specified ".. yet to be populated with values". The Python docs indicate "`None` is typically used to represent absence of a value". My example produced such a list of the defined size, in the shortest amount of code. Its the closest thing in idiomatic Python at the time the question was asked.

Comment: This meets the requirements of the question because you have a defined size array and you can index one of the five elements without getting an `IndexError`.  This is the closest thing to the C expression.

Comment: @user2233706 It would be closer to C if the array were populated with zeros.

Comment: You can do lst = [0] * 5 is you want

```>>>  [0]*5``` 
```[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]```

Comment: One thing to note: all elements in the list will have initially the same id (or memory address). When you change any element later on in the code, this will impact only the specified value, - HOWEVER - if you create a list of custom objects in this way (using the int multiplier) and later on you change any property of the custom object, this will change ALL the objects in the list.

Comment: this is not fixed size still one can use append method to add in a list

Comment: it is both mutable, extendable and not of fixed type. It is not actually an array at all.

There is actually a module `array` which has a fixed length, mutable singularly typed members accessibly by index.  This is the most relevant way of using a C-like arrray. Numpy Arrays have some common features, but limitations/quirks which make them not a suitable parallel of C arrays

Answer (score 110):

Why don't these questions get answered with the obvious answer?

```
a = numpy.empty(n, dtype=object)
```

This creates an array of length n that can store objects.  It can't be resized or appended to.  In particular, it doesn't waste space by padding its length. This is the Python equivalent of Java's

```
Object[] a = new Object[n];
```

If you're really interested in performance and space and know that your array will only store certain numeric types then you can change the dtype argument to some other value like int. Then numpy will pack these elements directly into the array rather than making the array reference int objects.

Comment: If it had been that obvious, though, someone else would have provided this.. again, importing a library just to get this functionality may not be the best option.

Comment: Except that this is the only answer here which is actually correct. The OP didn't specify that module loading was prohibited. Nor did he ask for a list. The question is very specific and this answer is correct. +1

Comment: adding a large module such as numpy is an unnecessary overhead

Comment: Can you explain why the choice of ``dtype=object`` as opposed to some other ``dtype``?

Comment: Just to clarify, does this implementation have the typical O(1) access time of an array as opposed to the O(n) access time of a linked list?

Comment: They said Python, not Python + Numpy.  Numpy is not a trivial add-on, either.  It can't be uninstalled and therefore is highly problematic for embedded Python uses.

Answer (score 65):

Do this:

```
>>> d = [ [ None for y in range( 2 ) ] for x in range( 2 ) ]
>>> d
[[None, None], [None, None]]
>>> d[0][0] = 1
>>> d
[[1, None], [None, None]]
```

The other solutions will lead to this kind of problem:

```
>>> d = [ [ None ] * 2 ] * 2
>>> d
[[None, None], [None, None]]
>>> d[0][0] = 1
>>> d
[[1, None], [1, None]]
```

Comment: Good answer. The problem you mention screwed me up at a programming competition. Do you know the exact mechanics under the bonnet to cause this?

Comment: Python copies "plain old data types" by value, and the rest by reference, and it's not always clear when one or the other is happening.

Comment: in case anyone wondering, the behavior is (TLDR first multiplier creates `n` length array, second multiplier creates a list of the arrays of `m` length by copying the first array by reference) explained here https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list

Comment: I had the exact problem.

Answer (score 18):

The best bet is to use the [numpy](https://numpy.org/) library.

```
from numpy import ndarray

a = ndarray((5,),int)
```

Comment: and would it be best?

Comment: It's not really the best to have to import a library just to use an array. Other ways exist.

Answer (score 15):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.zeros((3,4))
>>> x
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> y = numpy.zeros(5)   
>>> y
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

x is a 2-d array, and y is a 1-d array. They are both initialized with zeros.

Comment: You should provide a kind of explanation ...

Answer (score 14):

An easy solution is `x = [None]*length`, but note that it initializes all list elements to `None`. If the size is *really* fixed, you can do `x=[None,None,None,None,None]` as well. But strictly speaking, you won't get undefined elements either way because this plague doesn't exist in Python.

Comment: For most C use cass of an array, a normal (non-fixed) list is the idiomatic python equivalent. This is an answer to the question, as it probably helps the the OP (who is transitting from C to Python) most.

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> n = 5                     #length of list
>>> list = [None] * n         #populate list, length n with n entries "None"
>>> print(list)
[None, None, None, None, None]

>>> list.append(1)            #append 1 to right side of list
>>> list = list[-n:]          #redefine list as the last n elements of list
>>> print(list)
[None, None, None, None, 1]

>>> list.append(1)            #append 1 to right side of list
>>> list = list[-n:]          #redefine list as the last n elements of list
>>> print(list)
[None, None, None, 1, 1]

>>> list.append(1)            #append 1 to right side of list
>>> list = list[-n:]          #redefine list as the last n elements of list
>>> print(list)
[None, None, 1, 1, 1]
```

or with really nothing in the list to begin with:

```
>>> n = 5                     #length of list
>>> list = []                 # create list
>>> print(list)
[]

>>> list.append(1)            #append 1 to right side of list
>>> list = list[-n:]          #redefine list as the last n elements of list
>>> print(list)
[1]
```

on the 4th iteration of append:

```
>>> list.append(1)            #append 1 to right side of list
>>> list = list[-n:]          #redefine list as the last n elements of list
>>> print(list)
[1,1,1,1]
```

5 and all subsequent:

```
>>> list.append(1)            #append 1 to right side of list
>>> list = list[-n:]          #redefine list as the last n elements of list
>>> print(list)
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Well I would like to help you by posting a sample program and its output

Program:

```
t = input("")
x = [None]*t
y = [[None]*t]*t

for i in range(1, t+1):
    x[i-1] = i;

    for j in range(1, t+1):
        y[i-1][j-1] = j;

print x
print y
```

Output :-

```
2
[1, 2]
[[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

I hope this clears some very basic concept of yours regarding their declaration.
To initialize them with some other specific values, like initializing them with `0`.. you can declare them as:

```
x = [0]*10
```

Hope it helps..!! ;)

Comment: Your code doesn't define fixes-size array/list as requested in question. You just put some values in list, which still can be of any length

Comment: and why is it -1 while the +12 answer states the same way of doing so?

Comment: @lejlot because +12 answer is wrong too and similarly doesn't answer original question

Comment: I would not call them wrong, python simply does not have such low level access to memory management, while provided answers are really close to the expected behavior from the practical point of view

Comment: This solution does **not** do what you expect it to. `[[None] * t] * t` will create a list of `t` copies of **the same** "row". See [this question](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) in the Python FAQ.

Comment: @Lynn Thanks for this. I was puzzled for about a whole hour before I came here.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Descriptor, to limit the size

```
class fixedSizeArray(object):
    def __init__(self, arraySize=5):
        self.arraySize = arraySize
        self.array = [None] * self.arraySize

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.array)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.array

    def append(self, index=None, value=None):
        print "Append Operation cannot be performed on fixed size array"
        return

    def insert(self, index=None, value=None):
        if not index and index - 1 not in xrange(self.arraySize):
            print 'invalid Index or Array Size Exceeded'
            return
        try:
            self.array[index] = value
        except:
            print 'This is Fixed Size Array: Please Use the available Indices'


arr = fixedSizeArray(5)
print arr
arr.append(100)
print arr
arr.insert(1, 200)
print arr
arr.insert(5, 300)
print arr
```

OUTPUT:

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
Append Operation cannot be performed on fixed size array
[None, None, None, None, None]
[None, 200, None, None, None]
This is Fixed Size Array: Please Use the available Indices
[None, 200, None, None, None]
```

Comment: What point does your `def __get__(self, instance, owner):` have in this context? Instead, you should define `__(set|get|del)item__()`, the latter setting it/them to `None`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I find easy to do is i set an array
of empty strings for the size I prefer, for example

Code:

```
import numpy as np

x= np.zeros(5,str)
print x
```

Output:

```
['' '' '' '' '']
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with bytes you could use the builtin `bytearray`. If you are working with other integral types look at the builtin `array`.

Specifically understand that a `list` is not an `array`.

If, for example, you are trying to create a buffer for reading file contents into you could use bytearray as follows (there are better ways to do this but the example is valid):

```
with open(FILENAME, 'rb') as f:
    data = bytearray(os.path.getsize(FILENAME))
    f.readinto(data)
```

In this snippet the `bytearray` memory is preallocated with the fixed length of `FILENAME`s size in bytes. This preallocation allows the use of the buffer protocol to more efficiently read the file into a mutable buffer without an array copy. There are yet better ways to do this but I believe this provides one answer to your question.