# How to restrict the number of elements in python lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I came from `C` world where the size of buffers can be controlled in advance. For instance, declaring a buffer of doubles that holds 10 elements, we do:

```
double *buffer = calloc(10, sizeof(double));
```

In Python, it is quite the contrary in the sense that we don't need to worry about the details and the size of the buffer by saying `buffer=[]`.

My question is: If I want to restrict a python list to hold an arbitrary number of values, say 10 doubles, how can we do that with default python lists or maybe `numpy`?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311775/python-create-a-list-with-initial-capacity

Comment: I don't think this is a precise duplicate as user is open to `numpy`.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a duplicate of the linked question. Initializing to a length and actually restricting the length are not the same thing.

Comment: @jpp I added another to the dupe list with the same C foreword even.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Did you see the second duplicate in the list there?

Comment: Hmm, someone reopened this one. I'll turn my answer into a community wiki if/when it's dup'd correctly.

Comment: @miradulo nope, sorry, must have missed that, I see only one linked item. Could you be kind enough to repost it for me?

Comment: @PaulPanzer No worries. I marked it with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142689/initialising-an-array-of-fixed-size-in-python), though for NumPy [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535374/initialize-a-numpy-array) could be added too. I fail to see what is unique about this question.

Comment: @miradulo thanks. I'm still not convinced, I don't see any of the answers over there enforcing the list is not resized. And arrays with their slower `__getitem__` are not necessarily a suitable replacement.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I suppose we just differ in what we believe the OP is intending to ask. They closed with the first duplicate themselves - and a dynamically allocated array in C does not prevent resizing either.

Comment: @miradulo ok, let's leave it at that. If you want to start another close cycle I won't reopen.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Sure thing - I already VTCed earlier so I cannot. Here's another: [How to create a fix size list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617045/how-to-create-a-fix-size-list-in-python), with the answers I'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure an array is of a fixed size and of a certain type, you should use `numpy`. This is true even with non-numeric data.

Some examples are below.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.zeros(10, dtype=float)
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), dtype = float64

arr = np.zeros(10, dtype=int)
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), dtype = int32

arr = np.empty(10, dtype='<U8')
# array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
#       dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `deque` from collections that has a maxlen property.

```
from collections import deque
d = deque(maxlen=2)
```

You can then append, pop, iterate or do whatever you want with your restricted list.