# How to create the fixed length of empty list or array and append the required item from the starting index of list or array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

My requirement is l1 should be fixed length  & l2 length will be vary dynamically.

```
l1 = [None] * 24
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 
(or)
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5] 
(or)
l2 = list(range(40))
```

Now I need to append or insert the second list or array from the starting position.
My final output expected as below ( Means after append or insert the L1 length always 24)

```
Case 1:

    l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Case 2:

    l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,None, None,None, None,None None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

Case 3:
(Ignore after 24th index)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Is there any optimal solution using python list or numpy array or any other lib?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing it naively?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617045/how-to-create-a-fix-size-list-in-python 
please have a look this link for getting idea about the performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subscripting to assign l2 (or a part of it) to a subset of l1 (i.e. using the smallest length):

```
l1[:len(l2)] = l2[:min(len(l1),len(l2))]
```