# Python Typed Array of a Certain Size

Tags: python, arrays, performance, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

This will create an empty array of type `signed int`:

```
import array
a = array.array('i')
```

What is an efficient (performance-wise) way to specify the array lengh (as well as the array's rank - number of dimensions)?

I understand that `NumPy` allows to specify array size at creation, but can it be done in standard Python?

[Initialising an array of fixed size in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142689)
This deals mostly with lists, as well as no consideration is given to performance. The main reason to use an array instead of a list is performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialising an array of fixed size in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142689/initialising-an-array-of-fixed-size-in-python)

Comment: @sobolevn Which of those answers applies to my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array constructor accepts as a 2nd argument an `iterable`. So, the following works to efficiently create and initialize the array to 0..N-1:

```
x = array.array('i', range(N))
```

This does not create a separate N element vector or list.

(If using python 2, use `xrange` instead). Of course, if you need different initialization you may use generator object instead of `range`. For example, you can use generator expressions to fill the array with zeros:

```
a=array.array('i',(0 for i in range(N)))
```

Python has no 2D (or higher) array. You have to construct one from a list of 1D arrays.

The truth is, if you are looking for a high performance implementation, you should probably use Numpy.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking for. Do you know how to do a generator version to initialize to zeros? Can this be done for 2D or 3D arrays?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and fast to just use:

```
array.array('i', [0]) * n
```

[Timing](https://gist.github.com/autf/79689148aca0a324b180779d55f62eac) of different ways to initialize an array in my machine:

```
n = 10 ** 7
array('i', [0]) * n     #  21.9 ms
array('i', [0]*n)       # 395.2 ms
array('i', range(n))    # 810.6 ms
array('i', (0 for _ in range(n)))  # 1238.6 ms
```

---

You said

> The main reason to use an array instead of a list is **performance**.

Surely arrays use *less memory* than lists.

But by [my experiment](https://gist.github.com/autf/034de601584c9dfeef8d94a2c9995e71), I found **no evidence** that an array is *always faster* than a normal list.