# Creating a Two-Mode Network

Tags: python-3.x, social-networking

Using Python 3.2 I am trying to turn data from a CSV file into a two-mode network. For those who do not know what that means, the idea is simple:

This is a snippet of my dataset:

```
Project_ID    Name_1    Name_2    Name_3    Name_4 ... Name_150
    1           Jean      Mike
    2           Mike
    3           Joe       Sarah     Mike      Jean        Nick
    4           Sarah     Mike
    5           Sarah     Jean      Mike      Joe
```

I want to create a CSV that puts the Project_IDs across the first row of the CSV and each unique name down the first column (with cell A1 blank) and then a 1 in the i,j cell if that person worked on a given project. NOTE: My data has full names (with middle initial), with no two people having the same name so there will not be any duplicates.

The final data output would look like this:

```
            1             2              3              4              5 
Jean        1             0              1              0              1
Mike        1             1              1              1              1
Joe         0             0              1              0              1
Sarah       0             0              1              1              1
...        ...           ...            ...            ...            ...
Nick        0             0              1              0              0
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by using the [CVS reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects)

```
import csv

with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Note that row will read as arrays for each line.

The output array should probably be created before you start. As from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9126397/544198), here is how you could do that

```
buckets = [[0 for col in range(5)] for row in range(10)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, it is not working as stated in the question, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Not sure how to implement to get the needed output