# How to declare an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I want to assign values to different indices and not in a sequential manner(by using append), like we would do in a hash table. How to initialize the array of a given size?
What I do:

```
a=[]
for x in range(0,10000):
       a.append(0)
```

Is there a better way?
Also, is there any function like memset() in c++?

Comment: You can do `a =  [0] * 10000`

Comment: What about this? `a = [0 for i in range(10000)]`

Comment: That's a list.  To do that, say `a = [0] * 10000`

Comment: Thank You. Got it. I just started with Py and I couldn't find it anywhere online.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056768/how-to-declare-array-of-zeros-in-python-or-an-array-of-a-certain-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056768/how-to-declare-array-of-zeros-in-python-or-an-array-of-a-certain-size)

Comment: Are you sure you want an array? A dictionary (aka a hash) be better suited for your purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, initializing a `list` (not an array, that's not the type in Python, though there is an `array` module for more specialized use) to a bunch of zeroes is just:

```
a = [0] * 10000
```

If you want an equivalent to `memset` for this purpose, say, you want to zero the first 1000 elements of an existing `list`, you'd use slice assignment:

```
a[:1000] = [0] * 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize a list of a given size in several ways.

Python has **list comprehensions**, which create lists from other lists inline. So, if you make a list with 10000 elements (`range(10000)`) you can easily make from this a list with 10000 zeroes:

```
[0 for _ in range(10000)]
```

This is pretty close to your original solution.

Probably a more efficient approach is to multiply a list with a single zero by 10000:

```
[0]*10000
```

Both will yield a list with 10000 zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a call to "[memset](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/array.html#zero-overhead-unsafe-access-to-raw-c-pointer)" from [CPython](http://docs.cython.org/index.html):

```
    from cpython cimport array
    import array

    cdef array.array a = array.array('i', [1, 2, 3])

    # access underlying pointer:
    print a.data.as_ints[0]

    from libc.string cimport memset
    memset(a.data.as_voidptr, 0, len(a) * sizeof(int))
```

Comment: There is no indication that the OP actually wants to initialize a C array here. And definitely no indication of a desire to use Cython (which is _not_ the same thing as CPython; CPython refers to the reference interpreter which happens to be implemented in C).

Comment: In the post you can read "Also, is there any function like memset() in c++?" What the OP chooses to use to solve it's problem is pretty much his decision. Down-voting an answer just because it does not fit your idea of solution is a bit narrow from my point of view. But I'll defer to more informed opinion. If I see my post does not provide useful information for OP I'll delete it.

Comment: Even if the OP doesn't find the answer useful, somebody else reading this question may. If it's a legitimate answer and provides a new perspective on the problem, it is free to keep around and there is no need to delete it. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256350/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-got-negative-votes%3E